# Google sheets apps script to get values from other sheet and populate in another with conditions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

@tanaike

I have a google spreadsheet with three sheets
 `Product Details`, `Option Details` and `cc`

In the `cc` sheet, there is a column named `Action`,

When the user selects `Add Product` or `Add Option` , I want the first name from the `Product details` and `Option details` sheet to be pulled.

Please help me how to achieve this using formula or apps script.

I tried using apps script, it works well when I select and delete `Add Product`, but when I select `Add Option` all values change to Option Name.

The script name is `enhancement.gs` the code block with comment `//   PRODUCT NAME & OPTION NAME POPULATOR in cc sheet`

here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lQUG4TmFTKghV8r6Gg3EilLx6zyuTkrNfnCatRVWp_U/edit#gid=1917270863) to the spreadsheet-

Here is the code I tried-

```
else if(sheet.getName() === "cc"){ //   PRODUCT NAME & OPTION NAME POPULATOR in cc sheet
  //  Getting the Object 
    const Filled_LAST_ROW_MPCC = sheet.getLastRow();
    var range = "B17:B"+Filled_LAST_ROW_MPCC;
    var values = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();
    flattenedValues = values.flat();
    var dictionary_mpcc = {};
    for (var i = 17; i <= Filled_LAST_ROW_MPCC; i++) {
        var cellValue = sheet.getRange("B" + i).getValue();
    
      if (!dictionary_mpcc["B" + i]) {
        if(cellValue === "Add Product"){
          dictionary_mpcc["B" + i] = cellValue;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(dictionary_mpcc)


    //  Checking if the values contain "Add Product"
    if(flattenedValues.includes("Add Product")){
    // if(range.getColumn() === 2 && editedValue === "Add Product") {
    // if (sheet.getName() === "5. Marketplace/MPCC Details" &&
    //   range.getColumn() === 2 &&  // Assuming the dropdown is in column B
    //   editedValue == "Add Product") {

      // Getting the sheet and the values to fetch the Product name from
      prod_sheet = cpd.getSheetByName("Product Details");
      const Filled_LAST_ROW = prod_sheet.getLastRow();
      prod_sheet_values = prod_sheet.getRange("C13:C"+Filled_LAST_ROW).getValues();
      // console.log("C13:C"+Filled_LAST_ROW);
      console.log("prod sheet values", prod_sheet_values);

      outputArray = [];
      //  Now, the since the product table can expand to make sure we opnly take the elements from table, the "Yes" values always comes afyer the table and hence breakig at that point to get the rale entries only and not the entries outside the table
      for (var i = 0; i < prod_sheet_values.length; i++) {
        var value = prod_sheet_values[i][0].trim();
        if ((value === 'Yes') || (value === 'No')) {
          break;
        }
        outputArray.push(value);
        // deleting empty values from the array
        outputArray = outputArray.filter(value => value.trim() !== "");
        
      }
      console.log("Product Names", outputArray)

      // Offset from the dictionary_mpcc and update that cell with the velue in outputArray
      var keys = Object.keys(dictionary_mpcc);
      if (outputArray.length === 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
          sheet.getRange(keys[i]).offset(0, 1).setValue(outputArray[0]);
        }
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(keys.length, outputArray.length); i++) {
          sheet.getRange(keys[i]).offset(0, 1).setValue(outputArray[i]);
        }
      }

    }
    
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var range = e.range;
    var editedValue = e.value;
    if (sheet.getName() === "cc" &&
      range.getColumn() === 2 &&  // Assuming the dropdown is in column B
      editedValue !== "Add Product") {
    
      var adjacentCell = range.offset(0, 1);  // Offset to the adjacent cell
      adjacentCell.clearContent();  // Clear the adjacent cell value
    }
    

    if(flattenedValues.includes("Add Option")){
    // if (sheet.getName() === "5. Marketplace/MPCC Details" &&
    //   range.getColumn() === 2 &&  // Assuming the dropdown is in column B
    //   editedValue == "Add Option") {
      // Getting the sheet and the values to fetch the Product name from
      option_sheet = cpd.getSheetByName("Option Details");
      const Filled_LAST_ROW_option = option_sheet.getLastRow();
      option_sheet_values = option_sheet.getRange("C13:C"+Filled_LAST_ROW_option).getValues();
      // console.log("C13:C"+Filled_LAST_ROW);
      console.log("prod sheet values", prod_sheet_values);
      
      outputArrayoption = [];
      //  Now, the since the product table can expand to make sure we opnly take the elements from table, the "Yes" values always comes afyer the table and hence breakig at that point to get the rale entries only and not the entries outside the table
      for (var i = 0; i < option_sheet_values.length; i++) {
        var value = option_sheet_values[i][0].trim();
        if ((value === 'Yes') || (value === 'No')) {
          break;
        }
        outputArrayoption.push(value);
        // deleting empty values from the array
        outputArrayoption = outputArrayoption.filter(value => value.trim() !== "");
        
      }
      console.log("Option Names", outputArrayoption)

      // Offset from the dictionary_mpcc and update that cell with the velue in outputArray
      var keys = Object.keys(dictionary_mpcc);
      if (outputArrayoption.length === 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
          sheet.getRange(keys[i]).offset(0, 1).setValue(outputArrayoption[0]);
        }
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(keys.length, outputArrayoption.length); i++) {
          sheet.getRange(keys[i]).offset(0, 1).setValue(outputArrayoption[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    else if (sheet.getName() === "cc" &&
      range.getColumn() === 2 &&  // Assuming the dropdown is in column B
      editedValue !== "Add Option") {
    
      var adjacentCell = range.offset(0, 1);  // Offset to the adjacent cell
      adjacentCell.clearContent();  // Clear the adjacent cell value
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

First, please remove or rename `onEdit` function from your current Google Apps Script project. And, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. And save the script.

When you use this script, please edit "B17:B29" of "cc" sheet. By this, the script is automatically run with the simple trigger of OnEdit.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const { range, source, value } = e;
  const sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "cc" || range.columnStart != 2 || range.rowStart < 17 || range.rowEnd > 29) return;
  if (value == "Remove" || range.isBlank()) {
    range.offset(0, 1).clearContent();
  } else {
    const obj = {
      "Add Product": { sheetName: "Product Details", range: "C13:C24" },
      "Add Option": { sheetName: "Option Details", range: "C13:C25" },
    };
    const srcValues = source.getSheetByName(obj[value].sheetName).getRange(obj[value].range).getDisplayValues().reduce((s, [c]) => {
      if (c) s.add(c);
      return s;
    }, new Set());
    sheet.getRange("B17:C29").getValues().forEach(([a, b]) => {
      if (a == value && srcValues.has(b)) {
        srcValues.delete(b);
      }
    });
    const v = [...srcValues][0];
    if (v) {
      range.offset(0, 1).setValue(v);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is tested with your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- **This sample script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.**
- In the above sample script, after "Add Product" was selected 2 times and "name1" and "name2" were used, and when "Add Product" of "name1" was removed, only the value of "name2" was existing. Under this condition, when "Add Product" is selected, "name1" is put. If you don't want to put it in this situation, please test the following sample script.

  ```js
  function onEdit(e) {
    const { range, source, value } = e;
    const sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
    if (sheet.getSheetName() != "cc" || range.columnStart != 2 || range.rowStart < 17 || range.rowEnd > 29) return;
    if (value == "Remove" || range.isBlank()) {
      range.offset(0, 1).clearContent();
    } else {
      const obj = {
        "Add Product": { sheetName: "Product Details", range: "C13:C24" },
        "Add Option": { sheetName: "Option Details", range: "C13:C25" },
      };
      let srcValues = source.getSheetByName(obj[value].sheetName).getRange(obj[value].range).getDisplayValues().reduce((s, [c]) => {
        if (c) s.add(c);
        return s;
      }, new Set());
      sheet.getRange("B17:C29").getValues().forEach(([a, b]) => {
        if (a == value && srcValues.has(b)) {
          const t = [...srcValues];
          if (t[0] != b) {
            t.splice(0, t.indexOf(b) + 1);
            srcValues = new Set(t);
          } else {
            srcValues.delete(b);
          }
        }
      });
      const v = [...srcValues][0];
      if (v) {
        range.offset(0, 1).setValue(v);
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much @tanaike - san

will try this out

Answer (score 1):

**SUGGESTION:**

You could try this logic instead if this works for you:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

  //Access all 3 sheets
  var ccsheet = ss.getSheetByName('cc');
  var pdsheet = ss.getSheetByName('Product Details');
  var odsheet = ss.getSheetByName('Option Details');


  //Gets the value of each range that contains the Product Name and Option Name
  var actionTab = ccsheet.getRange(17,2, ccsheet.getLastRow() -16,1).getValues(); 
  var productName = pdsheet.getRange(13,3,12,1).getValues(); 
  var optionName = odsheet.getRange(13,3,13,1).getValues(); 

  //This just filters out blank arrays on the options provided
  var productNameF = productName.map(x => x.filter(y => y != '')).filter(z => z.length != 0);
  var optionNameF = optionName.map(x => x.filter(y => y != '')).filter(z => z.length != 0);

  //Counter to allocate the product name and option name 
  var pnCount = 0; 
  var onCount = 0; 
  actionTab.map((x,i) => {

    if(x == "Add Product"){
      console.log(productNameF[i]);
      ccsheet.getRange(17 + i,3,1,1).setValue(productNameF[pnCount]);
      pnCount += 1;
    }
    
    if(x == "Add Option"){
      
      console.log(optionNameF[i])
      ccsheet.getRange(17 + i,3,1,1).setValue(optionNameF[onCount]);
      onCount += 1; 
    }

    });

  // console.log(actionTab);
  // console.log(productNameF);
  // console.log(optionNameF);
}
```

You can add an onEdit Trigger on this function instead like so: [image]

**Sample GIF:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out @Century Tuna. will try this out